# Matlab Process on Windows Server hangs

Tags: sql-server, matlab, sql-server-2008, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2

I run a Matlab process from the task scheduler, on a WindowsServer 2008R2 VM running on VMWare.

The process gets data from a SQL database and does calculation. The process seems to 'hang' and not do any calculations when the servers are particularly with less activity(on weekends). But when I log in via RDP - the process seems to kick off or come alive and completes its execution.

I have done research about this and have configured the NIC to not to goto sleep when its inactive, from the OS level. 
Also I have a different application writing a log file to the Win200R2 server during that period hoping to keep the NIC alive. 
But none of the above fixes are working, and still the process hangs on weekends. I would love to hear what the community thinks about this ...

[VM Configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzKMQ.jpg)

Comment: What database server is it?

Comment: SQL Sever2008 r2 Enterprise

Comment: where do you configure NIC, at the VM or the VmWare level?

Comment: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-879FA851-2B24-49E6-B58F-F25D0E923D17.html this was the link I used to read on the VM ware level power options. right now the VM is configured to 'put the guest OS into standby mode and leave the virtual machine powered on' and wake on LAN is checked as well.

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the VM configuration in the question.

Comment: I just could not figure what was causing this, I moved to the process to the server running the SQL instance and it seems to run without hangup.